# Search in a ListView efficiently

Tags: flutter, reactive-programming

I have a `ListView` and I have a search `TextField`. When the user searches for anything the `ListView` should get filtered. I have implemented is roughly as below and it works.

I want to know if this can be done more efficiently.

Additionally, I also want to know can I avoid calling `setState` in `onChanged` of the `TextField` after the filtering on `dataCopy` been done.

I mean isn't `dataCopy` rendering my `ListView` shouldn't changes to it get reflected directly in the view, why do I still need to tell flutter to update the state of my tree?

Note: I want to perform the search locally and not asynchronously. For brevity I am not writing the full code here but it goes something like this:

```
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyWidgetState createState() => new _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  List<String> data = [];
  List<String> dataCopy = [];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    data = dataCopy = getDataAsynchronously();
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        TextField(
          onChanged: (text) {
            dataCopy.clear();
            for (String s in data)
              if (s.toLowerCase().contains(text.toLowerCase()))
                dataCopy.add(s);
            setState(() {}); // can I avoid calling this ?
          },
        ),
        Container(
          child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: dataCopy.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, i) {
              return ListTile(
                title: Text(
                  dataCopy.text,
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: `setState` is cheap. Multiple calls still only cause a single re-render. If the parts of the view you want to re-render are re-rendered without that `setState()` call, you can of course omit it. `setState() {}` looks quite weird though. It should rather be `setState(() {});`

Comment: Away from the machine I wrote it on hence the weird format, corrected it. So you mean `setState` on every key-up isn't going to be expensive. I am not re-rendering the `ListView` anywhere else, so without this call my search doesn't work, is there any other way? I was half-expecting that changes to the `list` on which `ListView` is working would get reflected without me having to discretely call `setState`.

Comment: No, Flutter expects `setState` to be called as signal to re-render. You can use some delay to only re-render after some amount of time has passed since the last key-up

Comment: Okay, thanks, a timeout would be good. How about using 2 lists can that be avoided as well?

Comment: 2 lists for what purpose?

Comment: I am using one to hold the full data, second to hold the filtered.

Comment: 2 lists is ok, but `dataCopy = data.where((s) => s.toLowerCase().contains(text.toLowerCase()).toList();` would probably be better.

Comment: U can use https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/debounce for patching the text change

Comment: Looks interesting Dinesh, will give it a shot

Comment: ’rxdart’ contains debounce is up-to-date and provides many more stream operators.